# Java JMS codes that are equivalent to the following mule JMS connector configuration?

Tags: java, mule, jms

Have to send json message to this closed-box mule system with Java, through a message broker of course (MQ/Solace).  But somehow the system won't parse the json string upon receiving.  After some query, all I get is this sample mule JMS config GUI snippet on publishing to the mule system.  So hopefully I can follow this and create the expected JMS message.

[image]
[image]

Just want to get the default correct first:

- Content-Type: application/json
  The question is the name used in mule, cause char '-' is not allowed in JMS, from another thread, I found "Content_Type". Java coding would be something like: `msg.setStringProperties("Content_Type","application/json")`?  And secondly, is "application/json" a String?  Cause mule seems to have this mimeType, which is causing other kind of trouble!
- Encoding: UTF-8
  In Java, could it be simply like this: `context.createTextMessage(utf8String)` or some other StringProperties?

---

Another snippet that I received, mule expression error or just not parsing an application/json string from my java application!?
Message is in json, and there are 3 main sections: headers, payload and signature.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you share the message and a more detailed description of the issues you are having it would be useful to understand the problem.

Comment: @aled The problem is the mule system not parsing a simple json message, either some property is missing, or the message format is incorrect.  And that's what I'm trying to figure out.  All I get is this snippet, and told to "follow" the settings...

Comment: I understand, but adding the complete error message will increase the chances that you get an answer. The error message could provide some details that help to identify the problem.

Comment: @aled Thanks for the reply.  Updated with an error snippet.  I'm hoping to get a more detailed log tmw.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a truncated screenshot is very limited to be truly useful. The complete message as text would be much more useful. From the little I see from  the message, it appears to come from a DataWeave expression. It looks like a JSON is being parsed as a String, so the expression fails. But without the flow showing the expression, its relationship to the connector, and the complete error message it is difficult to be certain if the issue comes from the connector or somewhere else.

Comment: @aled  Sorry, the dev is behind slow-cappy citrix, I would provide the text if possible.  But I was able to get the xml part for the 1st snippet, which I added after.  To my surprise, the content-type and encoding are really default settings.  So how do I set the content type on a jms message just that the mule JMS connector will accept.  And does the connector send json as something else other than raw text?

Comment: JSON is just text with an implicit format. The problem might be in a previous step.